# Numeric precision lost with external table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, external-tables

I have a problem with an external table. I have a file with couple of numbers and I want to load them into an external table. The problem is that when I load the data into the  table, the precision is not good for me. I need to load data into the table as they are in the file.

For example in the file I have 2,1123589E-11 but in the table it becomes 2.11E-11. I want in the table, instead, 2.1123589E-11.

This is the script that I used to create the external table:

```
CREATE TABLE COEFF_BUSINESS_EXT (
C1 BINARY_DOUBLE,
C2 BINARY_DOUBLE)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY COEFF_BUSINESS_DIR
  ACCESS PARAMETERS 
  (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    (
      C1 FLOAT EXTERNAL,
      C2 FLOAT EXTERNAL
    )
  )
  LOCATION('COEFF_BUSINESS.txt')
)
REJECT LIMIT 0;
```

Comment: How are you querying the table? It sounds like your client is just choosing to display the number with few significant digits. Try explicitly formatting the value as a string, or changjng the client settings (e.g. set numwidth in SQL Developer, I think, or numformat), if you're just casually checking it for now.

Comment: Thanks Alex,i try to format the value as string but the problem is the same. I try also to extend printed digits but nothing. I'm querying table like this: 'select to_char(c1),to_char(c2) from coeff_business_ext;'.

Comment: You aren't supplying a format though. What does `to_char(c1, '9.99999999EEEE')` show you?

Comment: it shows me 2.11000000E-11 but the number in the file is 2,1123589E-11.

Comment: i try also Round function but it seems like oracle read number like 2.11E-11  and trunc the rest.

Comment: It's the same....reading the file oracle trim number.

Comment: Is the text in the file actually `"2,1123589E-11"`? Your control file specifies `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` - if a comma is being used as a decimal point into the number field it may be causing a parse problem.

Comment: No no sorry,  the file use a point as a decimal point.

Comment: I can't replicate this in 11.2.0.4. Creating the table exactly as you've shown, and with the data file containing 2.1123589E-11 (period not comma), the full value is loaded. Querying through SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer with `select c1, to_char(c2, '9.999999999EEEE') as c2 from coeff_business_ext;` gives me `2.112E-011` and `  2.112358900E-11`. What is your exact version and patch level? (I'm sure it's not relevant, but why are you using binary double instead of just number column types?)

Comment: Thanks Alex, i change column type in Number and seems It works.

Comment: But now i have a new problem.External table read well numbers from file. But when i do operations with this Numbers and they are too small, Oracle rounds It to zero. How i can do to preserve the entire Number. For example Oracle round to zero 2e-376 but i want to preserve the entire Number or at least preserve the Number >0. I know that There are Oracle limit for the Number precision and scale but i Need the Number >0. Some suggestions?